# How can I Exclude methods completion from IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

I was reading [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html) in IntelliJ about Code completion. I found an interesting feature that enables to Exclude **Classes** From Code Completion.

I am wondering If I can do the same with certain **methods**? for example, It would be nice to exclude the deprecated and unused method from code completion.

Comment: can control-shift space (smart auto complete) help you sometimes?

Comment: Sure it Helps. But we want to optimize the code completion by removing undesirable methods from code completion. Maybe you should write a plugin for that :)

Comment: haha! maybe. but... doesnt it always prioritise the most used methods at the top? After time, wont it get used to your preferences? In any case, securing a return type and using smart complete should narrow the list drastically

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It does. I don't know about saving unused methods to preferences(to discard them). Actually, It was just curiosity that got me to ask this question, and I think the feature I am looking for does not exist yet in the IDE :)

Answer (score 2):

Please see/add/follow/comment the feature request already created for your question:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136103

For the current moment you can't exclude deprecated methods from completion list. Usually they can be grouped by selecting 'sort by relevance' option (right bottom corner of completion list). [image]

Comment: Alright cool. Is there any plugin that can do the job (hide methods in code completion)?

Comment: There are no official JetBrains plugins for this feature, you may try one suggested in issue comment, but I haven't tested it